# Is it OK to repost question from some other SO if it wasn't answered there?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I have asked a question on https://health.stackexchange.com as I thought it belongs a best there. But also I believe it would be on-topic here. 
As the health SO has much fewer users than biology it is not answered there.
Is it ok, (when it will be not answered for some time) to repost my question here, where the probability of the answer is bigger? If so, how long should I wait until it is appropriate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the answer is appropriate for both sites (which happens), you can always ask a mod to migrate it to biology (or where ever you think it fits better). There is no need to repost a question. If the Mod agrees, it will be moved.

Comment: Cross posting in general is even discouraged. Migration is indeed the way best option.